# Can Date objects be compared between timezones in Swift

Tags: swift

I have two date objects. One parsed from a server call in this form "2023-11-14T17:45:55Z" and a date object from adding minutes to .now.

I would like to write the code

```
serverDate > threeMinutesFromNow
```

But I want to be assured that this will work. I can't really find documentation on precisely HOW Date objects in swift implement comparable. If it's just by comparing timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate for the two AND that referenceDate is in a singular timezone I think this code is safe. But I am missing where I can check on this.

Comment: If you're doing it right, time is always stored as UTC then converted to local time only for display purposes,  With everything in UTC, you can match and compare across time zones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Date` objects, themselves, simply do not have timezones.

- That string, `2023-11-14T17:45:55Z`, represents the same instant worldwide, i.e., 5:45pm UTC (aka GMT) on the 14th, whatever that is in your local timezone.
- Likewise, `Date.now.addingTimeInterval(3 * 60)` (or however you are creating `threeMinutesFromNow`) represents a point in time worldwide. E.g., it is now 3:55pm in California, which is UTC-8, i.e., 11:55pm UTC; so 3 minutes from now is 11:58pm UTC.

So, using those example `Date` objects, the `>` operator will [compare](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/2963306) these two `Date` objects, i.e., comparing 5:54pm UTC on the 14th to 11:58pm UTC today.